Encontrei este erro no meu projeto em NextJS usando Swiper -> TypeError: mod is not a function
Meu código:

import styles from '../../styles/projects.module.css';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';
import { Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper';
import imgFilms1 from '../../../public/imgs/FilmsPage/imgFilms1.png'
import imgWeather1 from '../../../public/imgs/WeatherPage/imgWeather1.png'
import imgWeather2 from '../../../public/imgs/WeatherPage/imgWeather2.png'
import Image from 'next/image';

export default function Slider() {
    return (
        <section className={styles.cardsProjects}>
                <div className={styles.card}>
                    <Swiper
                        modules={[Navigation, Pagination]}
                        navigation
                        pagination
                        slidesPerView={1}
                        loop
                        className={styles.cardsSlide}
                    >
                        <SwiperSlide><Image src={imgWeather1} alt="weatherImage" className={styles.cardImage}/></SwiperSlide>
                        <SwiperSlide><Image src={imgWeather2} alt="weatherImage" className={styles.cardImage}/></SwiperSlide>
                   </Swiper>
                    <h2 title="Abrir GitHub deste projeto"><a href='https://github.com/davlp07/climaApp'>Aplicativo de Clima</a></h2>
                    <p>Este é um projeto de um aplicativo/software de clima-tempo, nele você pode encontrar o clima de
                        diversos locais, podendo pesquisar pelo nome ou coordenada do local desejado. Ele foi desenvolvido
                        usando NextJS, CSS e Javascript.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.card}>
                    <Image src={imgFilms1} alt="filmImage" className={styles.cardImage}/>
                    <h2 title="Abrir GitHub deste projeto"><a href='https://github.com/davlp07/TV-App'>Aplicativo de Filmes e Séries</a></h2>
                    <p>Este projeto é um software onde você pode encontrar informações sobre filmes e séries, podendo
                        favorita-los e pesquisar pelo nome do filme ou série desejada. Ele foi desenvolvido usando
                        HTML, CSS e JavaScript, usando WebPack como gerenciador de pacotes.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </section>
    )
}```

